# cpu saving continuous loop python

Tags: python, url, event-loop

the following text it my code so far, and it's working great the only problem is that the program takes a lot of cpu and making a hard time on my pc, I know that this is because of the while loop that never stops.
would like any recomendation for a continous loop that will keep the thing running but will not run so hard

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://animeisrael.website/watch/fulllink/op/fulllinkop-268.php")
browser.fullscreen_window()
me = 268

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('l'):
       browser.close()
       me+=1
       hello = str(me)
       browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
       browser.get("https://animeisrael.website/watch/fulllink/op/fulllinkop-"+hello+".php")
       browser.fullscreen_window()
       time.sleep(2)
       pyautogui.doubleClick(960,648)
       time.sleep(1)
       pyautogui.click(960,648)
       pyautogui.press('f')
```

I have read about asyncio event loops, and I have tried to use them but it didn't work quite well.
I would be happy for any suggestions even on the operating things I did in the code and things I can do , thanks for ahead :)

Comment: the time.sleep calls you have there should be enough for not "hitting the cpu too hard": you already doing what you ask for. Asyncio would be useful if you were running this code, but trying to keep retrieving stuff from more than one site at the same time.

Comment: increase the `time.sleep()` although as @jsbueno has said, it should already be sufficient...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you introduce a 'time.sleep' statement within the loop? Like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://animeisrael.website/watch/fulllink/op/fulllinkop-268.php")
browser.fullscreen_window()
me = 268

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust this value as needed
    if keyboard.is_pressed('l'):
       browser.close()
       me+=1
       hello = str(me)
       browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
       browser.get("https://animeisrael.website/watch/fulllink/op/fulllinkop-"+hello+".php")
       browser.fullscreen_window()
       time.sleep(2)
       pyautogui.doubleClick(960,648)
       time.sleep(1)
       pyautogui.click(960,648)
       pyautogui.press('f')
```